# DESCARGAR EXCEL DESDE LINK Y ABRIRLO INMEDIATAMENTE

Tags: excel, web, vba, scraping

Tengo este link que descarga un archivo excel cuando se pone en el chrome :

https://www.sbs.gob.pe/app/stats/seriesH-tipo_cambio_moneda_excel.asp?fecha1=03/01/2000&fecha2=24/02/2021&moneda=02&cierre=

El cual tiene como variables 2 fechas y un codigo de moneda;  "02" para USD.

Este link lo saque de este link : https://www.sbs.gob.pe/app/pp/seriesHistoricas2/paso3_TipodeCambio_Descarga.aspx?secu=03&paso=3&opc=1

Entonces mi idea es recontruir el link de la descarga del archivo excel para poder descargar el excel y que este inmediatamente sea abierto para poder trabajar en el .

Es posible descargar un archivo e inmediatamente abrirlo para trabajar en el ?

Answer (score -1):

podés tranquilamente lograr la descarga de tu archivo personal, sin embargo el abrir el documento ya no depende del sitio web, sino de tu computadora. A conitnuación te muestro como podes crear un "descargable" para tu excel.

`<a href="ACÁ VA LA RUTA DE TU EXCEL" download="">Descargar Excel </a>`